# SSRS images loaded by id from a network share/ sharepoint

Tags: image, networking, sharepoint, reporting-services, report

Is there a possibility to display an image from a network share/sharepoint in a SSRS report based on the entry ID that is being queried?

I know that it is possible to have an image from the [database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/images-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver16) but is it possible from an external source like shared drive/ sharepoint?

Example:

1. I have network shared folder "images". In it the images are called 1.jpg, 2.jpg etc.
2. In the SSRS report I query a database that returns results with ID 1, 2, 3 etc.
3. Based on the queried ID, images should be displayed accordingly - ID 1 = 1.jpg

Using an expression that checks if ID 1 then display 1.jpg wouldn't be a solution I think as there could be thousands of IDs, unless there's a way to write the expression to be dynamic, etc if x ID, then display //path/x.jpg.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `value` property of the image control to an expression, for example...

```
="\\myFileServer\myFolder\image" & Fields!FileNumber.Value & ".png"
```

Would return =`"\\myFileServer\myFolder\image1.png"` etc.

Be aware the the path must be visible from the server running SSRS (and also by the service account / user)

Start by adding a textbox with the path expression as above to make sure you are getting the values you expect and then set the image property once you are happy with the results.